# how can i build sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with date, the change name, the value of the change in cargo in stock like this:

```
Date|Change_name|Change_val|

2015.02.13 add 20

2015.02.13 del 5

2015.03.01 add 17

2015.03.01 add 2

2015.03.02 del 7
```

I want to get the table, which include day balance like this:

```
2015.02.13 15

2015.03.01 34

2015.03.02 27
```

How can i get this with SQL query?

Comment: Why are you storing it like that? It would be much easier to have just two columns, `Date` and `Change_val`, and use negative numbers when you want to subtract instead of recording "add" and "del". Because then you can just sum them up by group without needing to figure out which operation to perform.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk, thank you for your answer.Yes, i know, what is easier, but database seems like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `sum()` like below

```
  SELECT date, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Change_name='add' THEN Change_val*1.00 
      ELSE -(Change_val*1)) FROM table_name GROUP BY date
```